Bound on Hyperbolic Cosine Identity
I've worked on this problem for a day now and still can't find the desired bound. I want to show that
$$\frac{2\cos(2 \pi x)}{\cosh(2 \pi y)-\cos(2 \pi x)} \leq M, \ M\in \mathbb{R}$$
with the constraints that $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = N + \frac{1}{2}$ with $N \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. I'm particularly interested in the behaviour as $N \to \infty$.

Hint: the denominator is always strictly positive (why?)

Wait a moment this isn't true without more constraints. Like what happens when $x=0$?
